# How to find the time complexity?

Tags: performance, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Time Complexity for an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369061/time-complexity-for-an-algorithm)

Am I correct in my explanation when calculating the time complexity of the following algorithm?

- A HashSet, moduleMarksheetFiles, is being used to add the files that contain the moduleName specified. 
  -marksheetFiles is a Hashset.
  -if module is 'Maths' then any mark sheets with module 'Maths' gets added to the HashSet.

  ```
  for (File file: marksheetFiles){
       while(csvReader.readRecord()){
           String moduleName = csvReader.get(ModuleName);

           if (moduleName.equals(module)){
                 moduleMarksheetFiles.add(file);
           }
       }
   }
  ```
- Let m be the number of files
- Let k be the average number of records per file.
- As each file is added only once because HashSet does not allow for duplicates. HashSet.add() is O(1) on average and O(n) for worst case.
- Searching for a record with the specified moduleName involves comparing every record in the file to the moduleName, will take O(n) steps.

Therefore, the average time complexity would be: O((m*k)^2).

Is this correct?

Also, how would you calculate the worst case?

Thanks.

PS. It is not homework, just analysing my system's algorithm to evaluate performance.

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times.

Comment: Check this link, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nmallick/archive/2010/03/30/how-to-calculate-time-complexity-for-a-given-algorithm.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage